# Rebuilding Nginx with Extra Modules Using PPA

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, rtmp

I am trying to install the [RTMP module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. Here is what I've done...

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable
vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-ubuntu-stable-xenial.list
# Uncomment deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu xenial main
apt-get update

apt-get install dpkg-dev

mkdir /usr/src/nginx && cd /usr/src/nginx
apt-get source nginx
git clone https://github/arut/nginx-rtmp-module.git

cd nginx-1.12.2
vim debian/rules
# Added --add-module=/usr/src/nginx/nginx-rtmp-module to the full install flags

apt-get build-dep nginx
dpkg-buildpackage -b
cd ../
dpkg --install nginx-common_1.12.2-0+xenial0_all.deb nginx-full_1.12.2-0+xenial0_amd64.deb
```

However, when trying to run the install command I get the following error...

```
(Reading database ... 100580 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack nginx-common_1.12.2-0+xenial0_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.12.2-0+xenial0) over (1.12.2-0+xenial0) ...
Preparing to unpack nginx-full_1.12.2-0+xenial0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-full (1.12.2-0+xenial0) over (1.12.2-0+xenial0) ...
Setting up nginx-common (1.12.2-0+xenial0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx-full:
 nginx-full depends on libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam (= 1.12.2-0+xenial0); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam is not installed.
 nginx-full depends on libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext (= 1.12.2-0+xenial0); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext is not installed.
 nginx-full depends on libnginx-mod-http-echo (= 1.12.2-0+xenial0); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-http-echo is not installed.
 nginx-full depends on libnginx-mod-http-geoip (= 1.12.2-0+xenial0); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-http-geoip is not installed.
 nginx-full depends on libnginx-mod-http-image-filter (= 1.12.2-0+xenial0); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-http-image-filter is not installed.
 nginx-full depends on libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter (= 1.12.2-0+xenial0); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter is not installed.
 nginx-full depends on libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair (= 1.12.2-0+xenial0); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair is not installed.
 nginx
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot that part... updated the question to include it, @anx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is whats supposed to happen if you use packages from the artful (17.10) release. The Packages from the `/usr/lib/nginx/modules/*.so` modules were split out, so you could install them one by one. This has the nice side-effect that you will have a higher degree of freedom choosing what to recompile and install.

Two options:

- Use your Ubuntu versions supported version of nginx (remove the PPA version and follow the instructions of the module author as you did, in that version the modules should be all inside the nginx-full package)
- Use a newer nginx package, but do install its the split-out dependencies aswell (add them to you `dpkg -i` commands - you probably already produced the required packages - check the folder containing `nginx-common_1.12*.deb`)

Comment: How do I get the sources for Option 1 to add the module to? I'd prefer that method as it sets everything up nicely with sites-available/sites-enabled anyway.

Comment: I ended up using `dpkg --install libnginx-mod-* nginx-common_*_all.deb nginx-full_*_amd64.deb` and it worked well for me. Thanks :)